# Check transparency in .png image using jquery but without using canvas

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on an application in which I have placed the div background and I'm masking it with a .PNG image. In that .PNG image there is a transparent area from which user can see the background image of the div. I want to know if the user clicks on the transparent area or the white area of the .PNG image.

I have found this example:
[fiddle example using canvas](http://jsfiddle.net/cwolves/GaEeG/2/)

But I want to do this without using canvas. Is it possible?

I'm simply appending the png image on my div called drop.

```
var url = "url(./img/imagesapp/background.jpg?"+Math.random()+")";
$('.drop').css('background-image', url)          
var id=triangle;
var test="<img id='img"+id+"' class='shapeOfAC' src='./img/shapes/"+id+".png'/>";
$(".drop").append(test);
```

Thanks in advance :)[image: Image of my application]

Comment: You could test it server side by having the client make a AJAX request with what position in the image was clicked. But I don't think you can do it client side without a canvas.

Comment: Actually I want to use this on mouse-move event and the solution you are suggesting will do the work by making a lot of ajax calls but I want to avoid that.

Comment: maybe using an imagemap? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map

Answer (score 0):

The only real alternative I can think of (without serverside assistance) is to write some code that examines the PNG image to make a map of its transparency for each pixel and turn that into a long string containing just the alpha channel which you could read via javascript.

Problem with this though is that it'd be a lot of data. If you stored it just a lump of HEX it'd be 2xHxW bytes in length. Although you could improve this by gzipping the data and decompressing it in javascript.